# DRF How to save current user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm Trying to save an Item with the user's officeid but it's throwing me an error

> ValueError: Cannot assign "<CustomUser: admin@gmail.com>": "ClearanceItem.office" must be a "Office" instance.

My customuser has id of 1

while the email is admin@gmail.com

lastly the officeid = 'OSA'

this is my models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        userid = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=9)
        officeid = models.ForeignKey('Office', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='officeid', blank=True, null=True)

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

        objects = CustomUserManager()

class ClearanceItem(models.Model):
        cl_itemid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20, default=get_default_id)
        studid = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, null=True)
        office = models.ForeignKey('Office', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
        sem = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
        sy = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, null=True)
        remarks = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        resolution = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        resolve = models.BooleanField(default='False', blank=True, null=True)
        resolve_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
        resolve_by = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)
        recorded_by = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)
        record_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'clearance_item'

class Office(models.Model):
        office_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
        office_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        office_head = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)
        designation = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        office_parent = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
        deptlogo = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'office'
```

this is my views.py

```
class APIClerkView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = ClearanceItemSerialize

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(office=CustomUser.objects.get(officeid=self.request.user.officeid),
    recorded_by=self.request.user.userid)
```

Based on my previous encounter of this problem i think, it's not throwing an actual officeid but instead a string

How can I remedy that or Any alternative solution

My goal here is to avoid users type their officeid in a field along with other details.

```
    {
        "sem": "1",
        "sy": "2022-2023",
        "remarks": "TEST",
        "resolution": "TEST",
        "studid": "2012-5037"
    }
```

Comment: As the error says you are assigning an instance of CustomUser to office field in perform_create. Change it to office=Office.objects.get(office_id=…

Comment: it's throwing an error raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
users.models.Office.DoesNotExist: Office matching query does not exist.

Comment: office=Office.objects.get(officeid=self.request.user.officeid